# why are the duplicate elements returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, web-applications

```
 const cardChild = document.querySelectorAll('.card i');
 const cardsArray = ['a','a','b','b','c','c']; 
 const matchArray = [];

function cardsToClass() {
     for (i = 0; i < cardChild.length; i++) {

         let newCard = cardsArray.pop();
         let newCardClass = cardChild[i];
         matchArray.push(cardsArray[i]);

         newCardClass.className += newCard;
         console.log(cardsArray);
     }; }
```

Greetings! This function uses .pop() to 'pop' the cardsArray elements as a class in a DOM element.  My final result needs to be two identical arrays (cardsArray and matchArray).  I'm getting close. However when I console.log matchArray it returns:

```
 ['a','b','c',undefined,undefined,undefined]
```

I think something is happening at

```
 matchArray.push(cardsArray[i]);
```

but not sure. Does anyone know why its not returning the duplicate elements?

Thanks!

Comment: You want cardsArray to be ``['a','b','c']``?

Comment: Can you add your html?

Comment: I'm trying to make matchArray ['a','b','c', 'a','b','c'] like how cardsArray is.  However the last 'a' 'b' 'c' come up as undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are copying the array from the first positionto the last.
But by adding thwe `pop()` you are also removing the last item every time you use `pop` therefor half of the arry ends undefined.

Replace the `pop` for `unshift()` this will solve your problem.

I dont really get the purpose of the code but the html might help i you add it.

Hope this helps :>

```js
//const cardChild = document.querySelectorAll('.card i');
 const cardsArray = ['a','a','b','b','c','c']; 
 const matchArray = [];

function cardsToClass() {
     for (i = 0; i < cardsArray.length; i++) {

         let newCard = cardsArray.unshift();
         //let newCardClass = cardChild[i];
         matchArray.push(cardsArray[i]);

         //newCardClass.className += newCard;

     };
console.log(cardsArray);
console.log(matchArray);
}
     
cardsToClass()
```

Comment: You're right! thank you! That does give me the duplicate array's I need.  However without the .pop() it does't 'pop' those elements into the DOM.  I'll have to work that one out.  Thank you for putting me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because `.pop` actually modifies the source array.

See the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

---

Since `.pop` is modifying `cardsArray`, the array is actually shrinking as the loop progresses.

For each iteration of the loop, `cardsArray` starts as:

1. `cardsArray = ['a','b','c','a','b','c'];`
2. `cardsArray = ['a','b','c','a','b'];`
3. `cardsArray = ['a','b','c','a'];`
4. `cardsArray = ['a','b','c'];`
5. `cardsArray = ['a','b'];`
6. `cardsArray = ['a'];`

From this, it is clear that from the third iteration (`i = 2`) on `cardsArray[i]` is `undefined`

Comment: hmmm..... you are right.  I will need to eventually compare the cards and match array's.  I will try looking at cloning a 'new' cards array and 'pop' the old one